# setting up background image

Tags: android

i want to set the background like below

[image]

but i am getting like this

[image]

when i cropped the image to half i was getting like this (blur)

[image]

The original image is 
[image]

please guide how can i set like original one

xml files 
Grid xml

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/GridItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MyGrid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="80dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:scaleType="fitXY"   
     android:background="@drawable/backimage"
 >
</GridView>
```

I was thinking that it might be due to wrong xml placement so i also tried without gridlayout but no luck so far .

Now i have created multiple folder for images like this 
[image]
and in the manifest file add these line

```
<supports-screens  
     android:smallScreens="false"       android:normalScreens="true"
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

please guide what else need to be done

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The truth is the best way is to rescale the original picture to the dimensions of your screen. The picture you want is a cropped inset of the original. (The red on the right is almost gone). So one way is to change the margins. The numbers below will depend on your screen resolution.

[image]

And here is the Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:background="@drawable/love"
android:id="@+id/imageView1"



android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="-190px"
android:layout_marginRight="-210px"
android:layout_marginTop="-20px"
android:layout_marginBottom="-200px"

android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
```

> 

Comment: there is a problem with rotation , when the orientation is changed there is black strip appear on the screen

Comment: @umar you will need to recalculate your image if the orientation of the screen changes since it's width and height are no longer the same.

Comment: @ Andras Zoltan Thanks for advise . Do you mean  that i have to redefine the width and height again in the xml file

Answer (score 1):

Where you put :

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

I think you should use something like to maintain the image aspect ratio

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are facing several problems.

1. change the scale type to `CENTER_INSIDE`. I think this might be the one you want. Check others here: [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)
2. the blur may be caused by several things. I would put different drawables for different screen densities. See [Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: According to your suggestion i have done some work but still not working , please guide now how i can select hdpi for the updated question

Comment: open up an image editor and save the image with a different resolution. You can keep the same area drawn, but "save it using fewer pixels"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried forcing it to 32-bit?

Within your onCreate:

getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);